# Integration by parts $\int_{0}^{T}(h+\alpha t)\left[\frac{K}{(\theta-\gamma)}\left[e^{(\theta-\gamma) T-\theta t}-e^{-\gamma t}\right]\right] d t$

Tags: integration

I have no idea to process this integral
$$
\int_{0}^{T}(h+\alpha t)\left[\frac{K}{(\theta-\gamma)}\left[e^{(\theta-\gamma) T-\theta t}-e^{-\gamma t}\right]\right] d t
$$
Could someone explain step by step of process , thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write the integral as,

$$I=\frac{K}{(\theta-\gamma)}\int_{0}^{T}(h+\alpha t)\left(e^{(\theta-\gamma) T-\theta t}-e^{-\gamma t}\right)d t$$
$$=\frac{K}{(\theta-\gamma)}\int_{0}^{T}
\left(he^{(\theta-\gamma)T}e^{-\theta t}-he^{-\gamma t}
+\alpha e^{(\theta-\gamma) T}e^{-\theta t}t-\alpha e^{-\gamma t} t\right)d t$$

Then, use the integral results

$$\int_0^T e^{-at}dt = \frac1a(1-e^{-aT})$$
$$\int_0^T e^{-at}tdt =-\frac1a\int_0^T td(e^{-at}) 
= -\frac1a te^{-at}|_0^T + \frac1a\int_0^T e^{-at}dt $$

for each of the four terms in the integrand and simplify afterwards.